# Regex match for hyperlink

Tags: php, regex

I wanted to match hyperlink with different **Attributes** like href, rel, target, media. I am looking for a certain regex containing these attributes (rel, media are optional).

As i am inserting this code into my parser, i cannot afford to use DOM Class, so i am looking for solution with regex.

**Let me take below example to explain:**

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="follow" target="_blank">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

This is what i got now

```
    /<a\s?(href=)?('|")(.*)('|") (rel='|")(nofollow|follow)('|") target=('|")_blank('|") (media='|")(.*?)('|")>(.*)<\/a>/
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser for this, not a regex! (I'm sure you can "afford" it)

Comment: do you mind telling me how will it be better than regex.

Comment: Your regex is highly error prone, and will likely not be able to represent all of the possibilities of input that you will get, especially not in a single regex. Meanwhile, an HTML parser will always be able to handle any (valid) input you give it, and you will be able to easily extract the information you're looking for. If you'd consider using an HTML parser such as the built-in DOMDocument class in PHP, I can add an answer showing how you can achieve your goals.

Comment: [regex yaaaaay](http://regex101.com/r/mW9hD3). Note that using an HTML parser is waaay better, for example this regex won't match single quotes `<a href='http://www.google.com' target="_blank">Google</a>` and can give wrong results under certain circumstances.

Comment: @hamza-dzcyberdev i don't want to match '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>' then how will your code works

Comment: @ksreddy huh ? So what do you want to do ?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, just use a HTML parser ...

Comment: i want to match the hyperlink strictly containing href, target attributes but with rel and media attributes as optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class. I even incorporated your logic to check for required / optional attributes:

```
// Load up your HTML
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);

// Define attributes that we are looking for in name => required pairs
$attributes = array( 'href' => true, 'rel' => false, 'target' => true, 'media' => false);

$parsed_tags = array();

// Iterate over all of the <a> tags
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'a') as $a) {
    $tag_attributes = array();
    foreach( $attributes as $name => $required) {
        if( !$a->hasAttribute( $name)) {
            if( $required) {
                echo 'Error, tag is required to have ' . $name . ' attribute and it is missing' . "\n";
                continue 2;
            }
        } else {
            // Has the attribute, required or not lets grab it
            $tag_attributes[$name] = $a->getAttribute( $name);
        }
    }
    $parsed_tags[] = $tag_attributes;
}
```

With this HTML string:

```
$html = '<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Google</a><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="follow" target="_blank">Google</a><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>';
```

This [produces](http://viper-7.com/5Oqptx):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [href] => http://www.google.com
            [rel] => nofollow
            [target] => _blank
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [href] => http://www.google.com
            [rel] => follow
            [target] => _blank
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [href] => http://www.google.com
            [target] => _blank
        )

)
```

Note that with this solution, because I'm checking if the required attributes are present and doing `continue 2;` if they aren't this means that `<a>` tags without the required attributes are skipped, as seen in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/lxIuSj), where the tag `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>` outputs the error string I put in, but **does not** get included in the output array.

Comment: Thanks for your time for me. I am using mybb forum srcipt and i wanted insert regex in parser to match external urls and do some thing with it. First i thought having regex as for DOM again i have to use the HTML DOM.